# What's the best way to move a directory into place in a Makefile install?

Tags: linux, makefile, installation

I'm currently using the usual technique in my Makefile to install individual files:

```
install:
    install -D executable ${BIN_DIR}
```

But I just ran across a situation where I need to move a whole directory and all files underneath it into place.

Is `cp -r` the best way or is there a more linux-y/unix-y way to do this?

Comment: I never saw anyone who thought cp wasn't 'unixy'

Comment: "cp -r" is new school and doesn't have as many of the nice features that the install command does. I'm trying to stick to the usual conventions seen in Makefiles but this is one I hadn't seen.

Comment: the thing about install is that it's *not* very portable, and it is not very secure in, eg, an ACL environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, it's hard to think of a more unix-ish way that `cp -r`, although the -r is a relatively late addition to `cp`.  I can tell you the way we *used* to do it, and that works neatly across filesystems and such:

Let `src` be the source directory you want to move, and `/path/to/target` be an absolute path to the target.  Then you can use:

```
$ tar cf - src | (cd /path/to/target; tar xf -)
```

Comment: Spot the old-schooler, prepending dashes to tar(1) flags :) I still use this method a lot.

But you *definitely* want a && (not ;) in your subshell. If /path/to/target doesn't exist, you coud get some... interesting... results.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  You know, I'm not sure that && even worked when I first learned this trick.

Comment: I love the && operator... I'd also expect a check elsewhere in the script to see if the directory exists and create it otherwise, and exit if creation fails.

Comment: Oh, I agree.  I just don't think the bourne shell did that when I learned this idiom, back in the days of stone knives.

Comment: @CharlieMartin What is the tar doing in there? Does that result in a faster copy than (cp -r) ? Or is that simply for achieving the same goal when (cp -r) didn't exist yet?

Comment: `cp` didn't have the recursive option for a long time.  Using that `tar` pipeline was the *only* reasonable way when I started using UNIX.  Which was, admittedly, in the Triassic.

Comment: @CharlieMartin, I'm not sure when you learned this technique, but do I assume correctly that it predates the addition of the `-C,--directory` option to BSD and/or GNU `tar`? I only ask because I prefer `-C /path/to/target` rather than the subshell with leading `cd /path/to/target`.

Comment: Golly, it might very well predate *you*. I'm pretty sure I learned it in 1983 and it was a long-standing "look what you can do with pipes" example then.

Answer (score 4):

My version of `install(1)` (Debian) has:

```
   -d, --directory
          treat all arguments as directory names; create all components of the specified directories

   -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

So if you wanted to use `install(1)` consistently throughout your Makefile you could do:

```
install -d destdir
install srcdir/* -t destdir
```

`-t` isn't recursive however - if `srcdir` contains directories, then they won't get copied.

Comment: thats going to be very dependent on the version of install that is on the target system, it would be suitable if installing to a known OS (such as debian) but if a tgz is the distribution mechanism I'd assume he's trying to be as cross platform as possible.

Comment: Do you know any way to do such thing recursivly?

Answer (score 0):

Linking is another viable alternative. That would allow you to keep multiple directories (representing different versions) accessible.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't assume that they will keep the extracted tar.gz around after they've done the install so the whole thing needs moved.

Comment: you could consider hardlinking (which would get around the deleting the original files problem) however if the target is on a different file system/partition than the source the hardlink would fail.