# How to copy directories into a directory using install in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, installation

Assume the nested directories `foo/bar` and a empty directory `dest`.
I would like to call something like `install foo dest` such that `dest` contains the directory `foo/bar`.

I have tried the following:

`install foo dest` => install: omitting directory "foo"

`install -d foo dest` => nothing happens

Comment: `foo` can and will also contain files. It can be an arbitrary directory tree with unknown depth.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417236/whats-the-best-way-to-move-a-directory-into-place-in-a-makefile-install

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot copy entire directory trees with `install`. You have `cp` for that. You need to specify individual files with `install`. It's generally use for setting permissions on them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use `cp -r` instead:

```
cp -r foo dest
```

Comment: I get `install: target directory not allowed when installing a directory`

Comment: why not `cp -a`?

Comment: Why `install` is favored over `cp`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239279/223253

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP asked to do it with "install". `cp` will not set permissions

Answer (score 10):

```
install -D "${origin}"/* -t "${target}"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. + add a comment that it's on one level copy only.

Comment: no, this does not work. -D copies an empty directory structure and doesn't do what's asked here.

Comment: I get a 'install: omitting directory source/foo/' message and the folder 'dest/foo' is not created.

Comment: @schande It seems they have just changed the behavior. I don't see how to do this with `install` anymore 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but I just did this:

```
printf "Installing: %s\n      From: %s\n        To: %s\n" ${INSTALL_PLUGIN} ${SOURCE_PLUGIN_DIR} ${TARGET_PLUGIN_DIR}

FOLDER_LIST=$(find "${SOURCE_PLUGIN_DIR}/${INSTALL_PLUGIN}" -type d -exec realpath --relative-to=${SOURCE_PLUGIN_DIR} "{}" ";")

IFS=$'\n'
prev_folder=""
for folder in $(tac <<< "${FOLDER_LIST}"); do
    if [[ "${prev_folder}" != "${folder}"* ]]; then
        # echo "Processing: ${folder}"
        mkdir -vpm "${PLUGIN_DIR_PERMS}" "${TARGET_PLUGIN_DIR}/${folder}"
    fi
    prev_folder="$folder"
done

chown -R $TARGET_USER:$TARGET_GROUP "${TARGET_PLUGIN_DIR}/${INSTALL_PLUGIN}"


FILE_LIST=$(find "${SOURCE_PLUGIN_DIR}/${INSTALL_PLUGIN}" -type f -exec realpath --relative-to=${SOURCE_PLUGIN_DIR} "{}" ";")

IFS=$'\n'
for file in ${FILE_LIST}; do
    # echo "Processing: ${file}"
    install -v -p -o "${TARGET_USER}" -g "${TARGET_GROUP}" -m "${PLUGIN_FILE_PERMS}" "${SOURCE_PLUGIN_DIR}/${file}" "${TARGET_PLUGIN_DIR}/${file}"
done
```